# Unable to get Google Search work from Zsh

Tags: zsh

I have the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171563/whats-in-your-zshrc/187853#187853) in my .Zshrc

```
function google; {
             $VIEW "http://www.google.com/search?q='url-encode "${(j: :)@}"'"
     }
```

I get

```
google masi                                         
google:1: no such file or directory: http://www.google.com/search?q='url-encode masi'
```

**How can you get Google Search to work in Zsh?**

Comment: @Pax: Thank you for the tip! I managed to solve the problem by replacing $VIEW by open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the value of $VIEW?

Set it to the path of a web browser or downloader.

Comment: I accept the answer, since it suggests that the problem is in the value of $VIEW.

Answer (score 5):

The following solves the problem in Mac

```
function google; {
             open "http://www.google.com/search?q='url-encode "${(j: :)@}"'"
     }
```

and in Ubuntu

```
function google; {
             gnome-open "http://www.google.com/search?q='url-encode "${(j: :)@}"'"
     }
```

Comment: isn't this searching google for 'url-encode masi'?  Leaving out url-encode searches directly for whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know anything about zsh but looks like you've got a problem with your quotes.

Looks like it evaluates the url to being

```
http://www.google.com/search?q='url-encode masi'
```

Which probably isn't what you were after. (url encoded version of 'masi') ?

Comment: @Lou: True. I had initially a problem with smart quotes. Your quotation is also better than the original.